80s film about a boy confusing reality with the RPG he's playing
I'm looking for a movie from the 80s or early nineties about a boy playing an RPG that does overlap the real world and the characters from the RPG (a warrior with a sword or an axe, the alter ego of the main character). It may or may not be from Spain, but if I  recall correctly the protagonist life is in actual danger cause the boy is possibly confusing reality with his RPG. The kid sets on a quest which leads him on a tour around his hometown. It can be made for TV film.

Hard to say from the description, but could it be "Rona Jaffe's Mazes & Monsters."

I think it might be  El corazón del guerrero (The Heart of the Warrior). It's a 1999 Spanish movie directed by Daniel Monzón.

IMDB
Trailer

It could be Mazes and Monsters (1982)

Bound together by a desire to play "Mazes and Monsters," Robbie and
  his four college classmates decide to move the board game into the
  local legendary cavern.

